# Request, with limit(results) in mongodb with curl at php

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, limit

Perfectly i make the request and im getting the response. But i want to inject the "LIMIT" keyword at my query. At this moment my query is

```
'{"_id":"'.$id.'"}'
```

I also try this, and many random tries at this format

```
{"_id":"'.$id.'","limit":"6"}
```

With this i get all the rows. How and where can i inject the "Limit" MySQL's functionality keyword ? Note that i use GenieacsApi and i make a CURL request with unirest api. If you want more inforamtion. Please comment and i will provide them.

Comment: What is your actual `curl` request? Limit is normally a MongoDB query option, not part of the query itself (as in your current example). Based on [genieacs issue #214](https://github.com/genieacs/genieacs/issues/214) it looks like you should be able to include cursor options like  `limit` and `skip` as parameters in the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation of GeniacsApi I don't think you can limit results.

Apparently, **GeniacsApi** only allows raw queries and the "limit" functionality is a stage of the **aggregation framework**, not of the querying part.

If you cannot use the aggregation framework either the mongo client directly I don't think you can do it.

Comment: [`cursor.limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit) is definitely a feature of standard `find()` queries as well as aggregation. If this option isn't exposed through the GenieACS API you could add a feature suggest in the [GenieACS GitHub issue queue](https://github.com/genieacs/genieacs/issues).